# Why do these set of random variables converge in probability to $-1$?$(Y_n)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

$$Y_n=\frac{X_n}{1-X_n}=-1-\frac{1}{X_n-1}. X_n: \mathcal U(0,n)$$
So they unclear part is just the last equality in this series of equalities:

$$P\{|Y_n+1|\geq \varepsilon\}=P\{\frac{1}{|X_n-1|} \geq \varepsilon\}=P\{|X_n-1| \leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\}= \begin{cases} \frac{1+ \varepsilon}{n \varepsilon}, \frac{1}{n-1}<\varepsilon \leq 1 \\ \frac{2}{n \varepsilon} ,\varepsilon>0 \end{cases}$$

Why is this last equality like this is my only question.

Comment: As it is written now the last equality doesn't make sense. The case "$\epsilon>0$" includes in particular the case "$\frac{1}{n-1} < \epsilon \leq 1$"

Comment: Thats what I those, but either way I do not understand how $n$ is in the denominator

Comment: It comes from the fact that $$\mathbb{P}(X_n \in [a,b]) = \frac{b-a}{n}$$ for any $0 \leq a \leq b \leq n$.

Comment: Looking quickly, shouldn't the leftmost equality written in the question be an inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the very definition of the absolute value, we have

$$\mathbb{P} \left( |X_n-1| \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon} \right) = \mathbb{P} \left( X_n \in \left[1- \frac{1}{\epsilon},1+\frac{1}{\epsilon} \right] \right).$$

If $\epsilon \leq 1$, then $1- \frac{1}{\epsilon} \leq 0$. As $\mathbb{P}(X_n \leq 0)=0$ (because $X_n$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,n)$), we get

$$\mathbb{P} \left( |X_n-1| \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon} \right)= \mathbb{P} \left( X_n \in\left [0, 1+\frac{1}{\epsilon} \right] \right) \tag{1}$$

for all $\epsilon \leq 1$. On the other hand, we also know that $\mathbb{P}(X_n \geq n)=0$ and therefore

$$\mathbb{P} \left( |X_n-1| \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon} \right) = \mathbb{P}(X_n \in (0,n))=1$$

if

$$1+\frac{1}{\epsilon} \geq n \iff \epsilon \leq \frac{1}{n-1}.$$

If $\epsilon>\frac{1}{n-1}$, then $1+1/\epsilon \leq n$ and therefore it follows from $(1)$ and the fact that $X_n \sim U(0,n)$ that

$$\mathbb{P} \left( |X_n-1| \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon} \right) = \frac{1}{n} \left(1+ \frac{1}{\epsilon} \right) = \frac{\epsilon+1}{\epsilon n}.$$

Summarizing the above considerations we get

$$\mathbb{P} \left( |X_n-1| \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon} \right)  = \begin{cases} 1, & 0< \epsilon \leq \frac{1}{n-1}, \\ \frac{\epsilon+1}{n \epsilon}, & \frac{1}{n-1} < \epsilon \leq 1. \end{cases}$$